# How to use macros created in outlook 2007 to work in outlook 2010

Tags: macros

I recently was upgraded from Outlook 2007 to 2010.  I cannot see any of my macros that I created in 2007.  I also do not see any tags or buttons on how to call up any macros previously written in an older version.

What do I need to do, HELP

Comment: If you press ALT + F8 (opens the macros window) are the macros listed there?

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable the Developer tab to get the Macro buttons you are looking for:

1. On the File tab, choose Options to open the Outlook Options dialog box.
2. Click Customize Ribbon on the left side of the dialog box.
3. Under Choose commands from on the left side of the dialog box, select Popular Commands.
4. Under Customize the ribbon on the right side of the dialog box, select Main tabs, and then select the Developer check box.
5. Click OK.

[image]

More info from Microsoft: [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx)